# how to add this " keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }" in proguard

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to add  "keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }"  in progaurd  but i dont know how to do this ,  i dont have any idea about proguard  help me out

here is my gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.apnamall"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add the line code in here, proguard-rules.pro. Adding classes you want to keep from obfuscation.

[image: Proguard]

Comment: when i pasted this line  showing FLAG_TOKEN expected  with red line  why?

Comment: maybe you missing a dash ( - ), should be `-keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }`

Comment: my problem not solved ,  , please help me out, my problem is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182996/my-app-is-not-opening-with-the-errors-below

Comment: I m hoping  that after adding  this line in progaurd it will solve my issue but it can"t solved. plase have a look on my problem in the link